# When User Open One DropDown Close Other DropDowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I Want When User Click On One DropDown All Other open DropDown Get Closed . I looked  for answer in google but that is not working for my dropdown i know it's simple but i am unable to this pls help me !!

```
<div class="hh_drop_down">
<ul class="hh_main">

   <li class="hh_main_menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hh_sf">Chemicals</a>
     <ul class="hh_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Additives / Boosters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Anti-Allergen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Concrete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li  class="hh_main_menu" >
    <a class="hh_sf" href="#">Equipment</a>
      <ul class="hh_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Deodorization</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Duct Cleaning Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hard Surface</a></li>
     </ul>

  </li>

   <li  class="hh_main_menu" >
     <a class="hh_sf" href="#">Accessories</a>
      <ul class="hh_inner">
          <li><a href="#">Bonnets/Pads</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Brush/Rake/Sponge</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Carpet Rakes</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And jquery i am using in this :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".hh_main").on('click' , '.hh_sf' , function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        if($(this).next().hasClass('hh_inner')) { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hh_drop_down">
    <ul class="hh_main">

        <li class="hh_main_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hh_sf">Chemicals</a>
            <ul class="hh_inner expanded">
                <li><a href="#">Additives / Boosters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Anti-Allergen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Concrete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="hh_main_menu">
            <a class="hh_sf" href="#">Equipment</a>
            <ul class="hh_inner expanded">
                <li><a href="#">Deodorization</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Duct Cleaning Equipment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hard Surface</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="hh_main_menu">
            <a class="hh_sf" href="#">Accessories</a>
            <ul class="hh_inner expanded">
                <li><a href="#">Bonnets/Pads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brush/Rake/Sponge</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Carpet Rakes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hh_sf").next().addClass("collapsed").slideUp();

        $(".hh_main").on('click', '.hh_sf', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var currentClass = $(this).next().prop('class');
            if (currentClass == "hh_inner expanded") {
                $(this).next().removeClass("expanded");
                $(this).next().addClass("collapsed");
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            } else {
                $(".expanded").slideUp().addClass("collapsed").removeClass("expanded");

                $(this).next().removeClass("collapsed");
                $(this).next().addClass("expanded");
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJad8/1/)

Comment: It's working but when i click same link like if i am clicking Chemicals again i want that to close but it's not closing ..

Comment: when i am clicking 1 link two time it's not closing !! pls help me :)

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do, show all li as expanded when it is loaded or only one as expanded. May be this way,can help you achieve you requirement

Comment: Edited the code to slide up all the dropdowns at beginning & added Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I opened dropmenu with show and hide and made event on li  you can use different way

try this :

**JQuery :**

```
$(".hh_main_menu").click(
    function(){
        $(this).next(".hh_inner").toggle();
        if($(this).siblings(".hh_main_menu").children(".hh_inner").css("display")=="block")
        {
            $(this).siblings(".hh_main_menu").children(".hh_inner").hide();
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend you cache `$(this)` and `$(this).siblings(".hh_main_menu").children(".hh_inner")` in variables so you can re-use their result for better performance and to avoid code duplication. `var $this = $(this);` and then you can do `$this.next(...` and `var $hhInner = $this.siblings(".hh_main_menu").children(".hh_inner")` so you can do `$hhInner.hide();`. Speaking of `hide`, it's performance is terrible relatively speaking, so it might be better toggling a class to show/hide depending on the size / frequency of this operation.